# The gem wkhtmltopdf and pdfkit in a Rails app on Heroku produces an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pdf, heroku

I have a rails 3.2 app on heroku and these 2 gems:

```
ruby "2.2.4"
gem 'rails', '3.2.16'

# .......
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary-11'
gem 'pdfkit'
```

However, when I'm trying to generate pdf, I get the following errors:

```
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
```

Obviously, I can't install a library or update it on heroku to fix the errors. How to fix them? And the same kind of error I have locally, but I'm on Arch.

Answer (score 0):

The pdfkit wiki has [instructions on how to use on Heroku](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit/wiki/Use-with-Heroku) leveraging the buildpacks support.

buildpacks are the Heroku mechanism for building libraries, so it's not impossible, just another area for research.